# dot notation and accessing instance variable

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

So I was reading some other thread about using dot notation to access an instance variable and a definition was the following:

> By self.myVariable you are accessing the instance variable myVariable
>   and by myVariable you are accessing the local variable. They're not
>   the same thing.

This seems to be very confusing to me, especially coming from a java background. Can someone explain to me clearly what he means by local variable here? Is this the same thing as using this in java? If it is the same then in java if say you have:

```
private int myVariable;

int testFunction(int m)
{
  myVariable = 3;
}
```

This would access myVariable instance variable as there is no local variable defined in the method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Self.myVariable does not access the instance variable (most of the time there won't be a difference, there exceptions like when you have a custom setter). Instead it accesses the getter of the property. It is equivalent to:

```
[self myVariable];
```

If you want to access an instance variable directly you can use just:

```
myVariable;
```

If you want to access the instance variable of another object you can do:

```
otherObject->myVariable;
```

Although as Caleb says below in the comments, this is frowned upon.

Comment: so you're saying that the last answer on this question, point no. 2 is wrong? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6113755/iboutlets-instance-variables-and-properties-best-practices

Comment: +1 for the difference between ivar and property. Using -> to access some other object's ivars is generally poor form in Objective-C, though. It's not at all nice to poke around in someone else's ivars.

Comment: In objective-C if I don't use self.instanceVariable and just do instanceVariable = 3; what will this actually do? it's not accessing the setter, so what is it doing? I guess this is my confusing

Comment: Doing `self.instanceVariable = 3` is accessing the setter. So if the property is for an object, and it's a retain property when you do `self.instanceVariable = someObject;` it will retain the new value and release the old value.If you just access an ivar which has a retain property, directly (using ->) the new value will not be retained and the old value will not be released, leading to the old value being leaked and the new value not being retained and possibly being deallocated too early.Usually when getting a value it's ok to access it directly, the exception is if you have a custom getter.

Comment: @adit Point 2 wasn't exactly wrong, for that question the principle was correct but technically it was wrong. I've edited the point to (hopefully) be more clear.

Answer (score 0):

from what i know though the dot notation is just the new way of accessing things.  prior it would have been [self myVariable] where as now you can do self.myVariable.  the major differences between objective c and java (at least for this question) is how values or objects are passed in this call

[OBJECTIVE C (look at the messaging section)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Objective-C#Messages)

[JAVA](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/java/passing.html)

"By self.myVariable you are accessing the instance variable myVariable and by myVariable you are accessing the local variable. They're not the same thing."
this makes sense although i think its phrased weird
this is what they are saying

self.myVariable - instance variable of a class (happens to be self)

myVariable - local variable

foo.myVariable - instance variable of class foo

```
also remember "local" is the same as scope
so 
int x; //local variable to the class with a scope of the whole class

method foo{
int x; //local variable to the method with a scope of the method
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hm…. I'm not too sure what the definition is talking about, but a local variable is definitely a variable defined inside a method.  If you are the class that has the instance variable is accessing the instance variable, you should just go ahead and call it directly just by it's instance variable name.  However, if there's a local variable defined in the method, then it would get the local variable instead of your instance variable.

So for example

```
@interface Class : NSObject
{
    int instanceVariable;
}

@end

@implementation Class

-(id)init
{
    if (self = [super init])
    {
        //You can access your instance variable like this
        instanceVariable = 1;
    }
}

@end
```

By the way, to use the dot syntax, you must implement an accessor method or use the @property and @synthesize.

```
@interface Class : NSObject
{
    int instanceVariable;
}
@property int instanceVariable;
@end

@implementation Class
@synthesize instanceVariable;

-(id)init
{
…
}
@end
```

Comment: what happens if you don't define the property and synthesize or lets say just the property but not synthesize? compile error?